# Why can I not see the branch tree in TFS?

Tags: git, tfs, git-branch, git-commit

I'm not able to see the branch tree inside TFS web portal or from Visual Studio. If I open `gitk --all` I see a perfect tree of the branches.

Is it me that misunderstand something about git and TFS?

[image: gitk]

[image]

Comment: Aren't you able to switch the branch on the top left on the page where's "master" written? Normally you can only take a look at one branch

Comment: ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ have you tried asking Microsoft?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can only select **one** of the branches to see the Git graph (commit history) in TFS. But `gitk --all` will show all the branches' Git graph. So they are different.

You can try to run `gitk master` in git bash to check that, it should has the same Git graph (tree) with TFS.

Besides, to see the tree/nodes on the specific branch, you need to cross merge the branches/commits, normal straight commits on the specific branch will only shows as a line but not the tree structure.

Reference this article for Git graph experience: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/05/10/announcing-git-graph-and-advanced-filters-to-visualize-commit-history/

Also below articles to understand the Git:

- [Use gitk to understand git](https://lostechies.com/joshuaflanagan/2010/09/03/use-gitk-to-understand-git/)
- [Use gitk to understand git – merge and rebase](https://lostechies.com/joshuaflanagan/2010/09/03/use-gitk-to-understand-git-merge-and-rebase/)

Comment: Thanks, for the explanation. I did came to the same conclussion, but I just misses that overview of branches, that `gitk --all` provides. For example is there any commits that haven't been merged yet. It could have been an option to view all branches.